# Aiogram Webhook(heroku) Не работает FSM

Tags: python, telegram-bot, heroku, state, aiogram

При команде /start ставится state, потом если написать что-нибудь бот ответит(как и должно быть), а после перестает что-либо делать. Пробовал код в state.proxy() пихать(как сейчас), просто после state.proxy() писать. Не знаю что делать вообщем.

Код:

```
import os
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher, FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.utils.executor import start_webhook

TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']


WEBHOOK_HOST = 'https://типа url'  # name your app
WEBHOOK_PATH = '/webhook/'
WEBHOOK_URL = f"{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}"

WEBAPP_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
WEBAPP_PORT = os.environ.get('PORT')

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class Form(StatesGroup):
    hey = State()
    hey2 = State()
    hey3 = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def welcome(message: Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='hellO!')
    await Form.hey.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.hey)
async def hey(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['hey'] = message.text

        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='hello1')
        await Form.next()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.hey)
async def hey2(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['hey2'] = message.text

        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='hello3')
        await Form.next()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.hey)
async def hey3(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['hey3'] = message.text

        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='hello3')
        await state.finish()


async def on_startup(dp):
    await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL)
    logging.info(dp)


async def on_shutdown(dp):
    logging.info(dp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_webhook(dispatcher=dp, webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
                  on_startup=on_startup, on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
                  host=WEBAPP_HOST, port=WEBAPP_PORT)
```

Answer (score 1):

- `@dp.message_handler(state=Form.hey)`
  .
  .
  .
- `@dp.message_handler(state=Form.hey)`
  .
  .
  .
- `@dp.message_handler(state=Form.hey)`

Должно быть `hey`, `hey2`, `hey3`